# LiveData Doesn't Work With Nested ViewStubs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-livedata

I am using livedata and databinding in my project. And whenever i fetch data from webservices, i am databinding it with livedata. I can pass livedata object to first viewStub from root layout. It observes livedata as expected. But i am trying to pass this liveData to second viewStub which is placed in first viewStub. But it is not observing livedata when livedata's value changes.

root layout which is contains first viewStub:

```
<data>

    <import type="android.view.View" />

    <import type="android.text.TextUtils" />

    <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.test.test.MyViewModel" />
</data>

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/stub_import"
            android:inflatedId="@+id/panel_import"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            bind:viewModel="@{viewModel}" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

first viewStub layout which is contains second viewStub:

```
<data>

    <import type="android.view.View" />

    <import type="android.text.TextUtils" />

    <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.test.test.MyViewModel" />
</data>

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                      .
                      .
                      .
                      .

    <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/second_stub_import"
            android:inflatedId="@+id/second_panel_import"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            bind:viewModel="@{viewModel}" />

                      .
                      .
                      .
                      .

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the second viewStub layout which is using liveData from passed viewModel:

```
<data>

    <import type="android.view.View" />

    <import type="android.text.TextUtils" />

    <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.test.test.MyViewModel" />
</data>

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{viewModel.textLiveData}"
                android:textColor="@color/general_text_color"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And additionally i can replace second viewStub to "include tag". This would help as well but it is not observing either.

When a viewStub layout contains another viewStub or include tag, and passing some observable objects to these layouts. it won't observe.

Can anyone tell me any solution for this situation?